# Parse string with additional characters in format to Date

Tags: r, date, datetime, as.date

I have a string variable that I want to parse to class `Date`. In addition to the day, year and month, the format has other characters like separators (`,` ), letters and apostrophes (`u''`), like this:

`"u'9', u'2005', u'06'"`

I have tried

```
as.Date(my_data$date, format = '%d %Y %m')
```

...but it only produces missing values. I was hoping that R would interpret the `u''` as a unicode designator, which it doesn't.

How do I strip all those unused characters so that this `"u'9', u'2005', u'06'"` becomes simply this `"9 2005 06"`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to strip the characters not used in the conversion specification. In `?as.Date`, the `format` argument is pointing to `?strptime` ("Otherwise, the processing is via `strptime`"). In the Details section of `?strptime`* we find that:

> "[a]ny character in the format string not part of a conversion specification is interpreted literally"

That is, in the `format` argument of `as.Date`, you may include not only the conversion specification (introduced by `%`) but also the "other characters":

Furthermore, from `?as.Date`:

> Character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored

Thus, this works:

```
as.Date("(u'9', u'2005', u'06')", format = "(u'%d', u'%Y', u'%m")
# [1] "2005-06-09"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
as.Date(gsub("[u',()]","",my_data$date), format = '%d %Y %m')
```

Example with a single string:

```
d <- "(u'9', u'2005', u'06')"
d <- gsub("[u',()]","",d)
d.date <- as.Date(d, "%d %Y %m")
```

Result:

```
d.date
[1] "2005-06-09"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is character class, you can try:

```
library(lubridate)

test <- c("u'9'", "u'2005'", "u'06'")

dym(paste(gsub("u|'", "", test), collapse = "/"))
[1] "2005-06-09 UTC"
```

Here I use [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) to convert the string where I removed "u" and the ' character into time format.
The *collapse* character I used in `paste` is arbitrary, `lubridate` can handle pretty much anything as a separator between date parts.